# python + how to remove the message "cryptography is not installed, use of crypto disabled"

Tags: python, cryptography

First time programming in python and I guess you will notice it after reading my question:
  + How can I remove the message "cryptography is not installed, use of crypto disabled" when running the application?

I have created a basic console application using the pyinstaller tool and the code is written in python.
When I run the executable, I am getting the message "cryptography is not installed, use of crypto disabled". The program still runs, but I would prefer to get rid off the message.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

cryptography and crypto are 2 different modules.

try:

`pip install cryptography`

`pip install crypto`