# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'

Tags: python, cryptography

these are the Error messages I am geeting on running any of my project modules.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hsnl\BlockchainCodesTutor\Wallet.py", line 3, in <module>
    import Transactions
  File "C:\Users\hsnl\BlockchainCodesTutor\Transactions.py", line 2, in <module>
    import Signatures
  File "C:\Users\hsnl\BlockchainCodesTutor\Signatures.py", line 2, in <module>
    import cryptography
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'
```

I have already installed the cryptography module and was working perfectly until today I start getting this message that " No module named 'cryptography'".
I have again installed the cryptography as well as pip package but still showing the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be loose versions running on your system. Please try the following:

```
python -m pip uninstall cryptography
python -m pip install cryptography
```

You can also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60621653/python-how-to-remove-the-message-cryptography-is-not-installed-use-of-crypto/60646460#60646460) with `python -m` to make sure you are not using a loose pip.

Answer (score 1):

You might not have cryptogtaphy installed correctly. I see you are using windows. Open commandline **as an administrator** and run `pip install cryptography` again. Enshure that the installation finishes without any errors and consider to restart your python interpreter after installation.

For further help you should post more details like the output of `pip` and your code leading to the error, so a more detailed answer for your problem can be given.

Comment: Thanks for your response. After uninstalling and installing again the cryptography module on my system still getting the same traceback error.                
C:\Users\hsnl\Downloads>pip install cryptography
Collecting cryptography
Installing collected packages: cryptography
Successfully installed cryptography-3.3.1   -> After calling Import in python interpreter                                                   >>> import cryptography
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import cryptography
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'

Answer (score 0):

Try download cryptography whl from [here](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/#files).

Then use `pip install cryptography-XXX.whl`

For example:

```
pip install cryptography-3.3.1-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl
```

And now just supports python2.7 and python3.6.